# MySQL memory usage keeps growing. 30GB growth in 3 weeks

Tags: mysql, percona

We have a server with 64GB memory.

After restarting MySQL, in 3 weeks memory is almost full.

MySQL was installed using Debian Percona packages.

**Version: Percona Server Release 17 5.7.19-17-log**

In daytime, average selects per second are 2500.
Average writes per second are around 100.

Here is the `mysqld` config.
I'm not a DBA but I have access to server and MySQL root.

Are there any obvious problems? Thanks.

```
[mysqld]
skip-slave-start
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
server-id               = 2
relay-log               = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 1
max_binlog_size         = 1G
binlog_do_db            = gsa

user   = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port   = 3306
basedir    = /usr
datadir    = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir   = /tmp
lc-messages-dir  = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_ALL_TABLES
symbolic-links=0

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 512M
max-heap-table-size            = 512M
query-cache-type               = 1
query-cache-size               = 200M
query-cache-limit              = 10M
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 102400
table-definition-cache         = 16384
table-open-cache               = 400

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 32M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 20G
innodb-buffer-pool-instances   = 8


innodb_write_io_threads = 8
innodb_read_io_threads = 8
```

Comment: No obvious reason.  To dig deeper, I need more info.  Please provide the `GLOBAL STATUS` and `VARIABLES`; see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning for more details.

Comment: Hi, thanks.

GLOBAL STATUS; https://pastebin.com/msZNkVUg 

SHOW VARIABLES; https://pastebin.com/Urx1zaiB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did not spot a likely cause of the 30GB, but there are some issues to address:

**Observations:**

- Version: 5.7.19-17-log
- 64 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 23d 17:12:41
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

Normally I would suggest increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, but since the goal here is to figure out why so much RAM is being used; I will put that off.

Tables are being opened at a large rate.  Perhaps because of lots of short connections?  Perhaps queries with lots of tables?  The OS apparently has a limit of 1024 files per process.  This is unreasonably small for MySQL; try to change the OS limit (to, say, 4096) so that `open_file_limit` can go up, and then `table_open_cache` can go up -- to, say, 1000.

`'open_files_limit', '1024'` -- this disagrees with the unreasonable setting (102400) in my.cnf.  Probably the OS overrode it.

`innodb_log_file_size` is unreasonably low at only 32M; raise it to 200M.  (See the 5.7 manual for specifics on how to do that.)

Do you have essentially no "transactions"?  That is, are you happy with `autocommit=ON`?

Some of the details below indicate inefficient queries -- find them so we can discuss them and hopefully make them run more efficiently.

Are you using SSD drives?  (Some of the numbers hint that you are.)

Hundreds of `SHOW` commands are being run per minute.  (Production systems rarely need to run any `SHOW` commands.)  Are you using some 3rd party software that can't remember what the schema is?

**Details and other observations:**

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) = 220,833,222 / 2049161 = 107 /sec` -- Writes (flushes)
-- check innodb_buffer_pool_size

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size / _ram ) = 20480M / 65536M = 31.2%` -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool

`( Opened_tables ) = 84,342,523 / 2049161 = 41 /sec` -- Frequency of opening Tables
-- increase table_open_cache

`( Opened_table_definitions ) = 3,568,448 / 2049161 = 1.7 /sec` -- Frequency of opening .frm files
-- Increase table_definition_cache and/or table_open_cache.

`( open_files_limit ) = 1,024` -- ulimit -n
-- To allow more files, change ulimit or /etc/security/limits.conf or in sysctl.conf (kern.maxfiles & kern.maxfilesperproc) or something else (OS dependent)

`( Table_open_cache_overflows ) = 84,342,104 / 2049161 = 41 /sec`
-- May need to increase table_open_cache

`( Table_open_cache_misses ) = 84,342,523 / 2049161 = 41 /sec`
-- May need to increase table_open_cache

`( (Innodb_buffer_pool_reads + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed) ) = ((42793206 + 220833222) ) / 2049161 = 128 /sec` -- InnoDB I/O
-- Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size?

`( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 234,594,526,208 / (2049161 / 3600) / 2 / 32M = 6.14` -- Ratio
-- (see minutes)

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 2,049,161 / 60 * 32M / 234594526208 = 4.88` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size. (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( Innodb_rows_deleted / Innodb_rows_inserted ) = 94,976,602 / 102716752 = 0.925` -- Churn
-- "Don't queue it, just do it." (If MySQL is being used as a queue.)

`( Innodb_row_lock_waits ) = 398,208 / 2049161 = 0.19 /sec` -- How often there is a delay in getting a row lock.
-- May be caused by complex queries that could be optimized.

`( Innodb_dblwr_writes ) = 16,335,687 / 2049161 = 8 /sec` -- "Doublewrite buffer" writes to disk. "Doublewrites" are a reliability feature. Some newer versions / configurations don't need them.
-- (Symptom of other issues)

`( expand_fast_index_creation ) = OFF` -- ALTER and OPTIMIZE may be greatly sped up by using ON.
-- Probably better to be ON.

`( innodb_thread_concurrency ) = 0` -- 0 = Let InnoDB decide the best for concurrency_tickets.
-- Set to 0 or 64. This may cut back on CPU.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( local_infile ) = ON`
-- local_infile = ON is a potential security issue

`( bulk_insert_buffer_size / _ram ) = 8M / 65536M = 0.01%` -- Buffer for multi-row INSERTs and LOAD DATA
-- Too big could threaten RAM size. Too small could hinder such operations.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables ) = 2,577,361 / 2049161 = 1.3 /sec` -- Frequency of creating *disk* "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs
-- increase tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size.
Check the rules for temp tables on when MEMORY is used instead of MyISAM. Perhaps minor schema or query changes can avoid MyISAM.
Better indexes and reformulation of queries are more likely to help.

`( tmp_table_size ) = 512M` -- Limit on size of *MEMORY* temp tables used to support a SELECT
-- Decrease tmp_table_size to avoid running out of RAM. Perhaps no more than 64M.

`( (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit ) = (88969136 + 202120925 + 856731 + 0) / 7 = 4.17e+7` -- Statements per Commit (assuming all InnoDB)
-- Low: Might help to group queries together in transactions; High: long transactions strain various things.

`( Select_scan ) = 19,298,109 / 2049161 = 9.4 /sec` -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi + Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi ) = (88969136 + 856731 + 0 + 0 + 202120925 + 0) / 2049161 = 142 /sec` -- writes/sec
-- 50 writes/sec + log flushes will probably max out I/O write capacity of normal drives

`( expire_logs_days ) = 1` -- How soon to automatically purge binlog (after this many days)
-- Too large (or zero) = consumes disk space; too small = need to respond quickly to network/machine crash.
(Not relevant if log_bin = OFF)

`( innodb_autoinc_lock_mode ) = 1` -- Galera: desires 2 -- 2 = "interleaved"; 1 = "consecutive" is typical; 0 = "traditional".

`( slave_pending_jobs_size_max / max_allowed_packet ) = 16M / 4M = 4` -- For parallel slave threads
-- slave_pending_jobs_size_max must not be less than max_allowed_packet

`( slow_query_log ) = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10.000000 = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( back_log / max_connections ) = 92 / 214 = 43.0%`

`( Connections ) = 170,473,414 / 2049161 = 83 /sec` -- Connections
-- Increase wait_timeout; use pooling?

**Abnormally large (not necessarily "bad"):**

```
Binlog_cache_use = 130 /sec
Bytes_sent = 15636572 /sec
Com_release_savepoint = 0.042 /HR
Com_rollback_to_savepoint = 0.39 /sec
Com_savepoint = 0.042 /HR
Com_show_create_table = 0.39 /sec
Com_show_fields = 0.83 /sec
Com_show_table_status = 0.39 /sec
Com_show_triggers = 0.43 /sec
Com_update = 99 /sec
Created_tmp_files = 0.26 /sec
Handler_commit = 1423 /sec
Handler_savepoint = 0.084 /HR
Handler_savepoint_rollback = 0.79 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_not_young = 4570 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead = 9.24e+7
Innodb_master_thread_active_loops = 2.02e+6
Innodb_rows_deleted = 46 /sec
Open_table_definitions = 16,384
Performance_schema_digest_lost = 4.1e+7
Qcache_hits = 543 /sec       -- This seems strange since the QC is OFF
Qcache_inserts = 198 /sec
Sort_rows = 10139 /sec
Ssl_default_timeout = 7,200
Ssl_finished_accepts = 53
Ssl_session_cache_size = 0.0MB
eq_range_index_dive_limit = 200
innodb_purge_threads = 4
table_definition_cache = 16,384
```

**Note**

The buffer_pool will grow until it gets to 20GB.  So, I would expect MySQL to use some amount more than that, but not 30GB.  Did it keep growing after 30?

Comment: "ulimit -n" was indeed 1024, so i increased it.
Set table_open_cache = 1000 and innodb_log_file_size = 200M.
We dont use transactions, would autocommit = off help?
Yes we are using an SSD.
About the "show" command. That was my bad, i removed the show query. 
I also reduced tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size to 64M.
Innodb buffer pool was set to 45GB, but in around a week server started using swap.

Comment: Last night free -mh showed 5gb available memory and top showed %90 of the memory was used by mysql. I restarted mysql service and available memory went to 55gb. Now that innodb buffer is filled, available memory is 35gb and top says %40 of the memory is used by mysql.

Comment: Do not use autocommit=off.  Use transactions if you need them.  I was merely noticing how few you had.

Comment: 45/64GB -- swapping -- Ouch.  Is anything else running on the machine?  Hmmm... maybe the performance_schema is taking more space than I would expect.  (Swapping is _terrible_ for performance.)

Comment: It is indeed terrible. One and a half day after restart, available memory reduced to 32gb, mysql memory usage increased to %43.

Comment: @enesaltinkaya  Any chance you have mysqltuner.com report available?  It would show by engine type, how many tables exist and storage space and additional volume information.  Some of the recommendations mysqltuner will suggest should be ignored.

Comment: Hello, there are 34000 tables. Here is the mysqltuner output https://pastebin.com/Rbw8qia9

Comment: @EnesAltınkaya - Ouch!  34K tables is a lot.  Did you get `table_open_cache` fixed?  Maybe this is a major part of the memory bloat.

Comment: @EnesAltınkaya - I see that `table_open_cache_instances` is 16.  BTW, the link in the mysqltuner predates the existence of that setting.

Comment: show variables like '%open_cache%';

'table_open_cache', '1000'
'table_open_cache_instances', '16'.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to get my head around it. open_files_limit is 1024. Mysqltuner says it should be bigger than table_open_cache, obviously. 
It is a read only variable, ill have to restart mysql to be able to set it, which i cant do right away.

So, table_open_cache is 1000, open_files_limit is say 2000, ulimit -n 4000. It should be like that, right?

Comment: And there is innodb_open_files too. About the values above, would it be okay if they were set to much higher values, like open_files_limit = 30000, table_open_cache = 20000, ulimit - n 40000 ?

Comment: @EnesAltınkaya - Sure, give that a try.

Comment: I increased the limits. Im logging memory usage changes in random intervals. Ill report back.

Comment: Its not fixed but it is slowed down.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cj99zh6zczlxxbi/goo.png

Comment: Please re-plot the graphs to plot the x-axis based on time, not on sequence.

Comment: I created a copy of the excel page at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BOQY7ZFSexTQEYTKOjNu5cBJvNl-m8uu9wUCDoIrZ-k/edit?usp=sharing , you can inspect it there.

Comment: @EnesAltınkaya - Your "Date" column is a string.  Can you turn it into a "datetime"?  Better yet, turn it into a number of seconds since whenever.  The chart, as it stands, does not show the trend because the timestamps are not evenly spaced.

Comment: I converted date strings to unix timestamp in the same file above.

Comment: @EnesAltınkaya - Thanks.  That makes it clearer that the rise in memory usage is close to a straight line.  Alas, I am out of ideas of how to fix the runaway memory.

Comment: Dear Rick thanks a lot for all the effort and time you spent on this. For now we will just restart mysql every month. And soon hopefully we will rewrite the application from scratch without using this many tables.

Comment: @rickjames  Please look at these STATUS rollback numbers for the 23 days of uptime. 
Com_rollback, 0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint, 809380
Com_xa_rollback, 0
Handler_rollback, 29
Handler_savepoint_rollback, 1618760

Is the volume reasonable from your viewpoint?  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck - Interesting puzzle.  I see that on a few other machines, but I don't know what causes it, nor whether it is "bad".  `Com_savepoint` is 24, so your code is doing such.  And it seems like the code loves to "rollback to savepoint".  Can you search your code for "savepoint" to get some insight?

Comment: @rickjames I have asked Enes Altinkaya for 2 minutes of General Log with argument at a busy time of day to try to determine reason for rollbacks.  Enes has the source code.  Thanks

Comment: @EnesAltinkaya  could you post text results of 
A) SHOW CREATE TABLE gs_object_data_356173068748552; 
B) SHOW INDEX FROM gs_object_data_356173068748552; 
for DEADLOCK research   
C) SHOW CREATE TABLE gs_user_events_status; 
D) SHOW INDEX FROM gs_user_events_status;

Answer (score 0):

Things to do in my.cnf/ini to improve response time after your research,
  could be add, change or lead with # to disable

```
thread_cache_size=100 #from 50 to Ver 8 suggested CAP to minimize thread creation overhead
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  #from 262144 default to reduce RD per second
innodb_io_capacity=1500  #from 200 to use more of SSD capacity
#innodb_io_capaciity_max  # to disable default for auto calc of innodb_io_capacity * 2
innodb_write_io_threads=16  #from 8 due to heavy write load
innodb_page_cleaners=64  # for auto-limit = innodb_buffer_pool_instances
innodb_read_io_threads=16  #from 8 due to heavy read load
max_connections=350  #from 500, max_used_connections=224
max_write_lock_count=2  #from a huge number to allow RD opportunity
innodb_flush_neighbors=0  #from 1=ON to OFF with SSD there is no rotational delay
open_files_limit=90000  #from 60000 after adjusting ulimit -n to 100000
table_open_cache=60000  #from 29745 to reduce opened_tables RPS
table_definition_cache=25000  #from 16384 to reduce opened_table_definitions RPS
innodb_purge_threads=8  #from 4 to minimize purge backlog
```

10 seconds of your general log with arguments at a busy time would likely allow analysis to identify cause of thousands of com_rollback_to_savepoint activity.

Proceed cautiously, no more than 1 change per working day, do no harm.